# asp.net razor pages: binding checkbox result to dataset

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am completely new to a project I am to maintain.

Simply question: I have in my cshtml page (which I understand are razor pages?) set up a few checkboxes and a label to test the bound class behind it.

This I got to work:

```
@model Application.Areas.Cms.Models.ProduktBeispielViewModel 
<label>@Model.Test</label>
```

And the VM:

```
public string Test { get; set; } = "THIS IS A TEST";
```

And happy me: the words are displayed on my page. So the binding is working.

Now I put up a few checkboxes and once a submit button is pressed, I need to retrieve each checkbox and see if their value is checked or unchecked (shouldnt be too hard).

I first now just tried to display a value (eg true or false) from my VW onto my existing checkboxes.

This is what I did:

```
public bool Test2 { get; set; } = true;
```

CSHTML:

```
   <input type="checkbox" name="FoodTrends" value="@Model.Test2" />
```

I am seeing my checkbox, but it is unchecked.

1.) Why is my simple binding not working? is "value" not the right property?
2.) How would I retrieve my value from this checkbox

Thank you all!

Please have a look at this:

[image]

I am returning my model, with the value on Test2 being `false`

Now this is my exact code in my view:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="FoodTrends" value="@Model.Test2" checked="@Model.Test2" />
```

And the result is that the checkbox is checked, even though the value is set to false.

I have noticed also that my checkboxes are inside "`<form>`" tag.

EDIT:

Razorcode (briefly):

```
@model Application.Areas.Cms.Models.ProduktBeispielViewModel

@{
    ViewBag.PopupHeadline = "Produktbeispiele";
    ViewBag.PopupSubHeadline = Model.Item != null ? Model.Item.NameInCurrentLang : "";
    ViewBag.HideLanguageComparison = true;
}

@section TabMenu
{
    <ul>
        <li><a href="@Url.Action("Index", "ProduktbeispieleEditor", new { id = Model.Item.Id })" class="Active">Einstellungen</a></li>
        <li><a href="@Url.Action("Image", "ProduktbeispieleEditor", new { id = Model.Item.Id })">Bild</a></li>
    </ul>
}




<form action="@Url.Action("SaveIndex")" method="POST" id="idForm">
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.AutoCloseWindow)
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Item.Id)

 <input type="checkbox" name="FoodTrends" value="@Model.Test2" />

</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

The checkbox wouldn't work that way you have to use the **checked** attribute to get selected your checkbox.

```
 @model Practice_web.Models.TestModel

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Home Page";

}

<div class="text-center">
    <h1 class="display-4">Welcome</h1>
    <p>Learn about <a href="https://learn.microsoft.com/aspnet/core">building Web apps with ASP.NET Core</a>.</p>
</div>



<div>
    <input type="checkbox" name="FoodTrends" value="@Model.Test2" checked="@Model.Test2" />
</div>
```

> Action Controller

```
 public IActionResult Index()
        {
            var model = new TestModel { Test2 = true };
            return View(model);
        }
```

Here is the demo video link

[Demo Link](http://srecorder.com/s/nris)

Please try this. This works for me like a charm

Comment: Hello, unfortunately, this checks the checkbox irregardless of whther my model value is true or false. 

also, you wrote js code, but asp.net and razor is c#. thank you!

Comment: You want to post the value right ?

Comment: And one thing more it will be checked or unchecked on the bases of your model value.

Comment: Ofc, i set the model value to true and to false. but in both cases, the checkbox is checked. and yes, i wanna retrieve the value of whether the checkbox is checked or not

Comment: For posting the data it removes the onlclick event and js code. it will work accordingly.

Comment: Still, the checkbox is constantly chcked, even if i go public bool Test2 { get; set; } = false;

Comment: I have updated my answer, please also go through demo link

Comment: Thank you,. The video isnt working, but I updated my question. Please have a look at this.

Comment: The video is working its a live link. I don't know why isn't working for you I have also kept it in form it is working fine.

Comment: Please post your form code razor side

Comment: i did! check my edited answer

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is a bug or I just don't understand how razor pages work but I have to new up the model first in the AddModel method then it seems to pick up the default value I set in the POCO for my checkbox bool property.

```
[BindProperty]
public NewMember? User { get; set; }
public AddModel()
{
    User = new NewMember();
}
```